# Linq Query to Return Nested Arrays having specific Property Value

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, properties, nested

I've been scouring multiple resources and can't figure this one out; I am trying to filter an Array of objects based on a Property that is nested a couple levels deep.  I've simplified things, so let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A {
  B[] bb;
}

class B 
  C[] cc;
}

class C {
  string value;
}
```

And now the code:

```
A[] aa = ...;
A[] filteredAa = aa.Where(... //NEED HELP HERE
```

What I want to do is filter the aa array such that it gives me only those A elements that have at least one B element that have at least one C element has a value of "hello" (e.g. aa[0] would be included in the filteredAa array if aa[0].bb[3].cc[2].value = "hello").

Can this type of filtering even be done?  I think and hope this makes sense, but please let me know if I can clarify any further.

Comment: whats the issue? no results? an error? only one result where there should be 20?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my code sample from my question because it actually wasn't working at all. Howie got it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) - and it sounds like you need to use it twice:

```
var query = aa.Where(a => a.bb.Any(b => b.cc.Any(c => c.value == "hello")));
```

So working up from the inside:

- A `C` object is useful if its value is "hello"
- A `B` object is useful if *any* of its `C` values are useful
- An `A` object is useful if *any* of its `B` values are useful
- `Where` filters a sequence of `A` objects, leaving only the useful ones

You can use `ToArray()` at the end if you *really* want an array, but I would typically use `ToList` or just keep it as an `IEnumerable<A>`.

Comment: Great explanation, really puts the Any() method into context - didn't realize it was so easy.

Comment: how can I get value combined from A & C like ....Select(d => new {a.A, c.C})

Comment: @SZT: I'd need to know the exact details; it doesn't sound like it's really a very good fit for this question which is more about existence than projecting. I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details and a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet could you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69828436/713847

Comment: @SZT: Given that you're using LINQ to SQL, the answer will depend on knowing what that supports; it's been years since I've used it I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm actually using mongo as underlying db. so this linq gets converted to mongo query.

Comment: @SZT: Yes, but that doesn't mean that *every* LINQ query can be translated - as you've already shown in that question. I could write a LINQ query that would be fine in LINQ to Objects, but won't actually help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A[] filteredAa = aa.Where(a => a.bb.Any(b => b.cc.Any(c => c.value == "hello"))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for where `Value` is a specific value:

```
var result = aa.Where(a=>a.bb.Any(b => b.cc.Any(c => c.Value == "hello"));
```

If you just want to get all of those that have any value:

```
var result = aa.Where(a=>a.bb.Any(b => b.cc.Any(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Value)));
```

Comment: +1 i liked this because it used where its not null rather than hello, as his initial (unedited) question asked for results where value existed rather than where value was hello

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredAa = aa.Where(x => x.bb.Any(y => y.cc.Any(z => z.value == "hello")))
```

Comment: I am so sorry, It's too late, but next time, i'll do it;)