# How to get value from a parent class and a nested array child using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, mongodb-query

I have the following model to get data from database:

```cs
    public class CultureResource
    {
        public string KeyName { get; set; }
        public List<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Culture { get; set; }
    }
```

Now my goal is to get data for **a list of** `keys` & `culture` where `keys` matches with `CultureResource.KeyName` & `culture` matches with `Resource.Culture`. How can I write a linq query on a `IQueryable<CultureResource>` to get a result of `IList<Result>` where `Result` may look like the following:

```cs
public class Result
{
    public string KeyName {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

I have tried the following Linq, but it throws `$project or $group does not support {document}.` error:

```cs
public IDictionary<string, string> GetLocalizedValueList(string[] keys, string culture)
{
    // returns IQueryable<CultureResource>
    var cultureResources = _repository.GetItems<CultureResource>();     

    /***** This is the query *********/
    var query = from cr in cultureResources
              from r in cr.Resources
              where keys.Contains(cr.KeyName) && r.Culture == culture
              select new { cr.KeyName, r.Value };
              
    var result = query.ToList()
              
    //return some data
}
```

FYI: my underlying database is mongo

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
        var query = cultureResources.SelectMany(cultureResource => cultureResource.Resources.Select(resource => new { cultureResource.KeyName, resource.Value })).ToList();
```

Comment: This one doesn't check against culture or key

Comment: Ok get you, can try this
`var query = cultureResources.Where(cultureResource => keys.Contains(cultureResource.KeyName))
            .SelectMany(cultureResource => cultureResource.Resources.Where(resource=>resource.Culture==culture)
            .Select(resource => new { cultureResource.KeyName, resource.Value })).ToList();`